# Android studio - build gradle - Illegal escape entry

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I'm having an error [enter image description here][1]called 'Illegal escape character in string literal' when I tried to add the repositories in an android app's build Gradle to link a flutter module. How do I get rid of it?

```
String storageUrl = System.env.FLUTTER_STORAGE_BASE_URL ?: "https://storage.googleapis.com"
repositories {
    maven {
        url 'C:\Users\Acabes\AndroidStudioProjects\fresh_screen\build\host\outputs\repo'
    }
    maven {
        url "$storageUrl/download.flutter.io"
    }
}
```

It shows error in the line `'C:\Users\Acabes\AndroidStudioProjects\fresh_screen\build\host\outputs\repo'`

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGFvy.png][1]:

Comment: Remove the illegal escape character? Without a [mre], we can't really help you. Please don't post screenshots of code, post the actual code as code-formatted text. The problem is that the backslash is an escape, so in a path you need to double them (or use a forward slash). So instead of `C:\Users\Acabes\AndroidStudioProjects...`, use `C:\\Users\\Acabes\\AndroidStudioProjects...`, etc.. Do this for all the backslashes in the path.

Answer (score -1):

You should use double \  on the directory

```
 'C:\\Users\\Acabes\\AndroidStudioProjects\\fresh_screen\\build\\host\\outputs\\repo'
```

Comment: `use double \\ ` True, but lest this gets marked a duplicate, add to your answer: *Why* does this solve `Illegal escape entry` (and possibly *why is this solution advisable*).